# VIM quick fix: How to filter some text from error format string?

Tags: vim, filter, format, setting

For example, my build log is something like:

```
[Server01:/sourceroot/src/test01.cpp:3]This is an macro error.
```

I hope to set error format to detect

```
%f=src/test01.cpp, %l=3
```

So how to filter out the "Server01:/sourceroot/" string in my "set efm=" setting in .vimrc files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `/sourceroot/` is just the first component of the path:

```
let &errorformat = '[%[%^/]%#:/%[%^/]%#/%f:%l]%m'
```

However, it's probably easier to re-format the initial message before parsing it with `errorformat`.